# Multiple domain class binding in Grails controller action

Tags: grails, data-binding

Using grails 2.3.7. I am trying to use Grails controller action parameter binding. If I have this code:

```
class TestController {
    def test(MyClass1 myClass1) {
        log.debug(myClass1)
    }
}
```

myClass1 is correctly fetched from DB using `http://locahost:8080/myapp/test/test/1`. 
But now I want to pass two domain classes. I have tried this code:

```
class TestController {
    def test(@RequestParameter('obj1') MyClass1 myClass1, 
             @RequestParameter('obj2') MyClass2 myclass2) {

        log.debug(myClass1)
        log.debug(myClass2)
    }
}
```

And access using `http://localhost:8080/myapp/test/test?obj1.id=1&obj2.id=3`, nothing is fetched. Is this the right way to use data binding in controller actions? Or is this impossible?

Regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this and one of in your controller :

```
// binds request parameters to a target object
    bindData(target, params)
    // exclude firstName and lastName
    bindData(target, params, [exclude: ['firstName', 'lastName']])

    // only use parameters starting with "author." e.g. author.email
    bindData(target, params, "author")
    bindData(target, params, [exclude: ['firstName', 'lastName']], "author")

    // using inclusive map
    bindData(target, params, [include: ['firstName', 'lastName']], "author")

def User bindUser(params)  {
        def User user = new User()
        def Human human = new Human() 

           bindData(user, params["user"])
           bindData(human, params["humna"])
         if(!human) 
         human.save(failOnError:true) 
         if(!user)
         user.save(failOnError:true)
        }
         //alloha~
    }
```

Comment: This is useful, but is not exactly the solution to what I am asking. My intention is to keep the code as clear and standard as possible, if Grails can do it automatically. Perhaps, simply it is impossible.

Comment: impossible to what ? you need a clear code ? and grails does a binding ..if you dont want that then ? what is impossible ?